# linear-gradient background overwrites other elements (such as img or text)

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I am writing code with CSS and Bootstrap 4. I have made a background of gradient, but when I start adding other elements, such as images or text they appear to be basically invisible because of the gradient being on top of them. Is there a solution?

```css
.background{
    background-image: linear-gradient(to top, black, white);
    opacity: 0.3; 
    }
```

```html
<html>

<div class="background"> 
    <div class = "row"> 
      <img src"https://devfest.gdg-taipei.org/images/logos/google.svg"> 
    </div> 
</div> 


</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
<div class="background"> 
    <div class="background-curtain"></div>
    <div class = "row"> <!--First Section-->
        <img src="img.png"> 
    </div> 
    <div class = "row"> <!--Second Section-->
        <p>Hello</p> 
    </div> 
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.background{ 
        position: relative;
    }
    .background-curtain{
        position: absolute;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        background-image: linear-gradient(to top, black, white);opacity: 0.3;
        z-index: -100;
    }
```

Comment: Thank you it helped. But now another problem appeared: when I have finished working with this section and started working with another, the new one overlaps the end of the first one. What are the possible solutions?

Comment: Okay. Maybe You need to take curtain out of row. For ex:
<div class="background"> 
     <div class="background-curtain"></div>
     <div class = "row"> <!--First Section-->
            <img src="img.png"> 
      </div> 
     <div class = "row"> <!--Second Section-->
            <p>Hello</p> 
    </div> 
</div>

Comment: No, it does not work. The this is that there are two separate sections and they overlap. This is not as you wrote. Look there -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52725661/section-after-background-set-up-overlapping-the-previous-one

Answer (score -1):

```css
.background{
    opacity: 0.3; 
  }
  .row{
    position:absolute;
    background-image: linear-gradient(to top, black, white);
    z-index:0;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    top:0;
    left:0;
  }
  .image{
    position:relative;
    z-index:1;
  }
```

```html
<html>

<div class="background"> 
    <div class = "row"> 
    
    </div> 
    <div class="image">
      <img src="https://devfest.gdg-taipei.org/images/logos/google.svg"> 
    </div>
</div> 


</html>
```

As i understand your question,
may be this will help you